# Prepend fails on x-editable values of 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrapTable that is utilizing the x-editable plugin for dropdowns.

There is a method per [the documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/) to prepend values to a dropdown with a value of `''` and text of `Not Defined`. This works just fine, except when another option in my dropdown has a value of 0. If that is the case, that value shows as the prepended value of Not Defined, when it should show as False.

My Code:

```
var data = [{"Bool": 1},{"Bool": 0}];


$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  columns: [
    {
      field: 'Bool',
      title: 'Bool',
      editable: {
        type: 'select',
        'prepend': 'Not defined',
        'source': [{'value': 1,
                    'text': 'True'},
                   {'value': 0,
                    'text': 'False'}]
      }
    }
  ],
  data: data
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6pg9yg9/2/